# How to create an array of all ids having <input type="checkbox"> in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Following is my HTML code:

```
<!-- Following is the code for parent checkbox-->
<input id="ckbCheckAll" class="custom-check ez-hide" type="checkbox" name=""></input>
<!-- Following is the code for child checkboxes-->
<input id="practice_6_191" class="custom-check ez-hide" type="checkbox" onchange="enable_text_boxes('practice_6_191')" value="191" name="practice_topics_6[]"></input>
<input id="practice_6_190" class="custom-check ez-hide" type="checkbox" onchange="enable_text_boxes('practice_6_190')" value="190" name="practice_topics_6[]"></input>
<input id="practice_6_191" class="custom-check ez-hide" type="checkbox" onchange="enable_text_boxes('practice_6_191')" value="191" name="practice_topics_6[]"></input>
<input id="practice_6_192" class="custom-check ez-hide" type="checkbox" onchange="enable_text_boxes('practice_6_192')" value="192" name="practice_topics_6[]"></input>
<input id="practice_6_193" class="custom-check ez-hide" type="checkbox" onchange="enable_text_boxes('practice_6_193')" value="193" name="practice_topics_6[]"></input>
<input id="practice_6_195" class="custom-check ez-hide" type="checkbox" onchange="enable_text_boxes('practice_6_195')" value="195" name="practice_topics_6[]"></input>
<input id="practice_6_196" class="custom-check ez-hide" type="checkbox" onchange="enable_text_boxes('practice_6_196')" value="196" name="practice_topics_6[]"></input>
```

Now I want to create an array of ids of the above `<input type="checkbox">` HTML elements and access this array using foreach loop on the click event of the parent checkbox.

That is when the parent checkbox is checked all the child checkboxes should also get checked, when the parent checkbox is unchecked all the child checkboxes should also get unchecked.

when user checks all the child checkboxes one by one then the parent checkbox should also get checked and when the user unchecks any of the child checkboxes when the parent checkbox is checked at that time parent checkbox should also get unchecked.

Can you help me in this regard please?

Also, one more important thing is I don't want to access the child checkboxes with the help of class selector i.e. class="custom-check" or class="ez-hide" as these classes are common to all the child checkboxes. I want to create a an array and then access this array in my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use [**.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var id_checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```